# LINQ grouping and aggregating data with conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have some problems understanding a way to get the correct result from my LINQ query.

Let me first define the entity `ProductFavorite`

```
public class ProductFavorite
{
    public Guid Uid {get; set;}

    public Guid ProductUid {get; set;}

    public bool IsFavorite {get; set;}

    public bool IsLastUsed {get; set;}

    public int LastUsedYear {get; set;}
}
```

I have an `IEnumerable` of some favorites products, named `allFavorites`, containing objects made in the way I wrote before.

This "list" can contain elements with duplicates `ProductUid`, because it is build from different data sources.

And again: the items in the "list" have at least `IsFavorite = true` `OR` `IsLastUsed = true`.

I want to create, using LINQ of course, a resulting list of `ProductFavorite` objects, but grouping the items by ProductUid, and also grouping the three properties as follows:

> IsFavorite will be true only if one of the grouped items has this property set to true
>
> IsLastUsed will be true only if one of the grouped items has this property set to true
>
> LastUsedYear will be the maximum value of LastUsedYear of the grouped items

I've tried the next syntax, but I'm not sure it can give me what I want:

```
var favorites = 
        from ProductFavorite pf in allFavorites
        group pf by pf.ProductUid into distinctFavorites
        select new ProductFavorite()
        {
            Uid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            ProductUid = distinctFavorites.Key,
            LastYearUsed = distinctFavorites.Max(l => l.LastYearUsed) // ???,
            IsFavorite = ...,  // ???
            IsLastUsed = ...   // ???
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LastYearUsed` (or `LastUsedYear`?) line looks OK. For the last two you'll want

```
IsFavorite = distinctFavorites.Any(l=>l.IsFavourite),
IsLastUsed = distinctFavorites.Any(l=>l.IsLastUsed)
```

(assuming you mean "*any* one of the items has it set to true", not "*exactly* one of the items...")

Comment: Yeah...I thought I was near! Thnk you very much, also for the explanation of LINQ "Any" method...

Comment: No problem MAXE, congrats on getting more of the way there yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var favorites = (from ProductFavorite pf in allFavorites
                             group pf by pf.ProductUid into distinctFavorites
                             select new ProductFavorite()
                {
                    Uid = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    ProductUid = distinctFavorites.Key,                    
                    IsFavorite = distinctFavorites.Any(p => p.IsFavorite == true),
                    IsLastUsed = distinctFavorites.Any(p => p.IsLastUsed == true),
                    LastUsedYear = distinctFavorites.Max(l => l.LastUsedYear) 
                });
```